# Shortcut to open Network Connections from Run

Tags: windows, networking, keyboard-shortcuts, home-networking

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open Network connections from the Run command?

Comment: See [this (very) long list](http://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows) of useful commands on Windows over at SF.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ncpa.cpl` should work.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from ncpa.cpl, here's the registry trick:

Start -> Run and type the below bold text

**explorer.exe ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}**

I tried this in Windows XP. It works well. It should work with Vista too.

You can create a shortcut of above command too!

Comment: doesn't look all that short :P

Comment: LOL - well said.  Just trying to explore many ways to do same thing.

Comment: That can easily be shortened to `explorer %network%` after you add an environment variable for that.

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Run

In run type this following command

ncpa.cpl